# Using IMapper in Integration Tests

Tags: ninject, integration, automapper, xunit

As the title says, I'm writing integration tests and do want to test and initialize the IMapper object as part of these tests.

I am using XUnit as the testing framework and Ninject to handle dependency injection.

I'm used to using the static AutoMapper methods and am shifting to use the IMapper interface, which is a parameter in one of my repository constructors.

I have a DependencyRegistrar class that inherits the NinjectModule base class.

My Load method is below:

```
public override void Load()
    {
        var automapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfile>(); });
        automapperConfig.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        var mapper = automapperConfig.CreateMapper();

        Bind<IMapper>().ToConstant(mapper).InSingletonScope();
        Bind<IUserManager>().To<UserManager>().InTransientScope();
        Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>().InTransientScope();
    }
```

This module is loaded by the NinjectWebCommon class in the API project, but obviously doesn't get loaded during the integration tests.

```
ConfigurationSettingsEntity configurationSettings = new ConfigurationSettingsEntity(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings);
        var modules = new INinjectModule[] { new DependencyResolution.DependencyRegistrar(configurationSettings) };
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(modules);
```

So, my question is, what's the best way to load the real mapper implementation so that I can pass that mapper into my repository's constructor when I build out the integration test?

```
UserRepository tester = new UserRepository(mapper);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's definitely worth the effort to shift away from using the static Mapper - testing will be much easier going forward!

In my unit tests, I use code like the following:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { 
    cfg.AddProfile<MyProfile>();
});
IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

In each test suite, I manually specify the profiles needed for those tests.

Comment: That worked great for getting the mapper to load. Thanks!